# Cleanup "recalculation" carts in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

In my Shopware 6.4 project there are a lot of entries in the `cart` database table with the `name` "`recalculation`". After some code analysis they look to me like carts created only for temporary use for example during order recalculations or context creation from orders, but are not needed afterwards and are just garbage. Is it so? Can they be safely deleted without any negative side effects?